# Nodemailer with Gmail error: 454 4.7.0 Cannot authenticate due to temporary system problems

Tags: node.js, express, gmail, gmail-api, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer module with my nodejs/express.js app.

I am using gmail as the transporter.

It seems like every 20 successful emails sent, I will get this error:

**454 4.7.0 Cannot authenticate due to temporary system problem**

I'm testing out an invoice system so I'm regularly sending an email to the same email address for testing.

I am not using Google apps and I have set Gmail security to work with low security apps.

Invoices are important and if I cant guarantee all invoices will get sent to my customers, its going to be bad.

Is this normal?

```
app.get('/thankyou', function(req,res) {

  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
      auth: {
      user: 'somethinggggg@gmail.com',
      pass: 'password here'
      }
    });

   res.render('thankyou_email', function(err,html) {

     var mailOptions = {
       from: 'John Doe <somethinggggg@gmail.com>',
       to: 'someoneee@icloud.com',
       subject: 'Your order was received',
       html: html
     };

     transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
       if(error) {
        console.log('error1: ' + error);
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
          if(error) {
            console.log('error2: ' + error);
          } else {
            console.log('cool bro everything works2');
            console.log(info);
          }
        });
       } else {
        console.log('cool bro everything works');
        console.log(info);
       }
     });

     res.render('thankyou_page');
});
```

As you can see, if I have an error I try to resend the email again, but still I receive the same error.

Also notice that I am using res.render() twice. I thought this was weird but it still works. The first res.render() I am using to generate the html for the email, and the last res.render() is to render the html in the response back to the client. I used to get an error about sending headers twice, but I don't see that error no more. Nevertheless ,it still worked.

Whose fault is this? Me? Nodemailer? Gmail?
If I were to sign up for Google apps will I still have this problem?

Comment: Which version of nodemailer and node you are using? I am using node 4.4.2 with latest nodemailer without any issues.

Comment: @gunjan I am using v4.1.2 with node.js and the latest version of nodemailer

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue? Reading some threads online, it seems it's an internal Google issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across [**Nodemailer**](https://nodemailer.com/) documentation and it was stated in [Using OAuth2](https://nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/using-oauth2/) that if a XOAuth2 token generator is used as the value for `auth.xoauth2` when setting up transporter object then you do not need to set the value for `user` or `pass` as OAuth2 is used for authenticated.

> XOAuth2 generator generates required `accessToken` itself if it is missing or expired. If authentication fails, a new token is requested and the authentication is retried once. If it still fails, an error is returned.

Sample code is given in the documentation. Though, I haven't personally tried using it, I hope it works with you. :)